# Performance tag requires eleboration

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tag-cleanup-request

Not entirely certain from my observations of this tag but I seem to see that this tag is always linked to other tags such as hard drive or graphics card or seems to be relatively broad, I was thinking would it not be best to break it down into specific performance issues such as slow drive performance slow CPU performance or graphical and sound performance for instance?

Comment: I think those tags are not even something we want to attempt to handle because of the vague nature of the word "performance" and questions that contain it.  In other words it will be connected to question that are likely not on topic here at Superuser.

Comment: Fair point I agree it was a vague suggestion. if it wont really help any I don't see any reason to attempt a clean up. Just curious, this is nothing personal but are you monitoring me? you seem to be everywhere on my posts haha

Comment: **I am active in the community.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I certainly agree with you that [performance](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/performance) is a horrible tag.

In part, this is due to the fact that performance-related questions are always horrible troubleshooting questions which don't result in a solution.

If anything, I would get rid of the tag because, as you've pointed out, the scope it covers is simply too broad to be helpful. But I would prefer not to take any action at this point.

Comment: Um, the tag for "this is a good suggestion, but not now" is [meta-tag:status-deferred], not [meta-tag:status-declined].

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi: No

Comment: Oh, wait, it only applies for feature requests.